# What does the ">>=" operator mean in C#?

Tags: c#, operators

I just came across the following code and I can see `num` decreasing by half each loop, but I can't sincerely figure out what that means.

```
int n1 = n;
for (int num = 16; num != 0; num >>= 1)
{
    if ((n1 & num) != 0)
    {
        dOSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Googling the title of your question produces some pretty promising results.  Have you tried to look into this issue at all before posting the question?

Comment: Yes, I did. Maybe you could show me a Google Result?? Thanks

Comment: [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.80).aspx) was the second result when I did the search.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tutoring.

Comment: But why don't the other results make sense at all? I just missed that result

Comment: Because your search keywords have a lot of overlap with information on other operators.  Removing some of the un-useful keywords and searching for just "C# operator >>=" helps, or even just searching for "C# operators" to find a list of all of them and going within a site from there.  As to why others have more google juice than "operator >>=" it's mostly because it's used (and therefore search for) less than most of those other operators.

Comment: Searching for "C# specification" and then searching the spec would also be a productive way to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right shift assignment operator:

`num >>= 1` is the same as `num = num >> 1`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/23as4533(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It means ['right-shift-and-assign'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/23as4533%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), along the same lines as `+=` means 'add-and-assign', `-=` means 'subtract-and-assign', etc.

For example:

```
int i = 123; // i = 123 binary 01111011
i >>= 1;     // i = 61  binary 00111101
i >>= 1;     // i = 30  binary 00011110
i >>= 1;     // i = 15  binary 00001111
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be the right shift assignment operator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/23as4533(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

it means shift right by 1 and assign, 16 is 10000 binary, every time you call that piece of code the number will essentially be divided by 2. 10000 (16) becomes 01000 (8)

Answer (score 0):

It is the operator that bit-shifts the value to the right. In your code, num will have the following sequence:

16 //10000 in binary

8  //01000

4  //00100

2  //00010

1  //00001